# How should a function passed to _arguments for zsh shell completion look like?

Tags: shell, scripting, zsh, tab-completion, zsh-completion

In my completion function, I'd like to add an option which possible arguments depend on which files are on the system. I have no troubles getting that list of possible arguments, but I have no idea what I should do with it.

[This guide](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/blob/master/zsh-completions-howto.org#actions) talks about `FUNCTION` as possible action for `_arguments`. (For some reason I didn't find it in the official docs) And that works well, the function specified is indeed called. But what should I now do with that list? I tried returning it and printing it. In both cases nothing happened.

`_files` manages to do it somehow, but from looking at the source code I didn't find anything useful. I probably have to store it in some variable, but where?

My code so far:

```
#compdef _command command

function _command {
    local line

    _arguments -C \
        '(-)'{-h,--help}'[Show help]' \
        '(-u --update -p --platform)'{-u,--update}'[Update]' \
        '(-p --platform -u --update)'{-p,--platform}'[Platform]:whatshouldiputhere:_get_all_platforms' \
        "*::arg:->args"
}

function _get_all_platforms {
    # I know how to get the list of possible completions but I have no idea what to do with it
}
```

Comment: You're making it hard to answer "what should I now do" by just circumscribing what you did instead of showing the precise code.

Comment: Sorry, I've added my code to the post

Answer (score 0):

> But what should I now do with that list?

You should pass it as arguments to the [`compadd`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#Completion-Builtin-Commands) builtin command:

> This builtin command can be used to add matches directly …